# Sign preserving Galois automorphisms

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-groups, roots-of-unity

I have an algebraic number $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, where $\zeta^n = 1$ is a root of unity (not primitive) given as a linear combination of powers of $\zeta$, i.e, $\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \zeta^i$, where $k < n$. If I knew that $\alpha$ was actually a real algebraic number, is there a characterization of those automorphisms $\phi \in Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})$ which preserve the sign of $\alpha$?

Comment: Have you looked at the archimedean absolute values on the real field $\Bbb Q(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$? Even in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_8)$, $\sqrt2$ is not totally positive, but $2+\sqrt2$ is.

Comment: @Lubin can you elaborate a bit on your remark? If it helps, in my problem, $n$ is not fixed. I could try and represent $\alpha$ in a different extension field.